# When was Peter's mother-in-law healed? Chronological contradiction?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, gospels, chronology, synoptic-problem

---

- Jesus cured Simon Peter's mother-in-law after he cleansed the leper:
  Matt. 8:15
- Jesus cured Simon Peter's mother-in-law before he cleansed the leper:
  Mark 1:30-42, Luke 4:38-5:13

---

- Peter's mother-in-law was healed before Peter was called to be a
  disciple: Luke 4:38-39, Luke 5:10
- Peter's mother-in-law was healed after Peter was called to be a
  disciple: Matt. 4:18-19 & 8:14-15, Mark 1:16-17 & 1:30-31

---

How might one explain this apparent chronological contradiction found in the Gospels? Is there a cogent, palatable explanation to this?

Comment: Please quote the passages so that we can more easily see the alleged contradiction.

Comment: Are you asking why [Matthew 8:14-15] does not declare the events took place immediately after leaving the synagogue on Shabbat - in contrast to Mark 1:29 & Luke 4:38?

Comment: You need to show directly the two contradictory propositions explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The Synoptic Gospels present numerous events in different sequences. Why?

**The Argument from Order**

The argument from order is used by students of the [Synoptic Problem](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synoptic-problem), but it may also be applicable here. The argument compares the order in which individual pericopes (“stories” for our purposes) are presented in each of the Synoptic Gospels in order to try to determine which author used which as a source.

It’s worth pointing out that if presenting material in a different order is a “chronological contradiction” then there are literally scores of chronological contradictions in the Synoptic Gospels alone. Their passion narratives are more closely aligned (though not perfectly) in terms of what happened after what, but the ministry portions of the Synoptic Gospels differ wildly.

My own study of the argument from order has led me to 4 conclusions that have bearing on the question in the OP:

1. None of the Synoptic authors were trying to present the material in a strictly chronological sequence
2. Matthew principally organizes his Gospel by topic (like an encyclopedia)
3. Luke principally organizes his Gospel by geography (like an atlas)
4. Mark borrows from Matthew & Luke, sometimes following the order of one and sometimes the other (like somebody telling stories from memory)

A more extended discussion of these points in the context of the argument from order, with whiteboard drawings of relative order, is found in [this video](https://youtu.be/L6iBtu9FQCw) (disclaimer: I made this video).

**An answer from our earliest source**

That the Synoptic Gospels do not present their material in the same order has been known and discussed for more than 1900 years.

Our earliest written discussion of the subject comes from Papias, Bishop of Hierapolis, writing about the Gospel of Mark in the very early 2nd century, discussing what he had learned in the 1st century from first generation Christians. His words, as recorded by Eusebius:

> The Elder used to say: Mark, in his capacity as Peter’s interpreter,
> wrote down accurately as many things as he recalled from memory—though
> not in an ordered form—of the things either said or done by the Lord.
> For he neither heard the Lord nor accompanied him, but later, as I
> said, Peter, who used to give his teachings in the form of chreiai,
> but had no intention of providing an ordered arrangement of the logia
> of the Lord. Consequently Mark did nothing wrong when he wrote down
> some individual items just as he related them from memory. For he made
> it his one concern not to omit anything he had heard or to falsify
> anything. (see HE 3:39, translation by Bauckham)

**Conclusion**

If we expect the Gospel authors to write in a 21st century style, we will be disappointed. They were not trying to present a day-by-day travel log, but a collection (from what must have been a much larger pool of material) of the teachings and sayings of Jesus they believed were most important for the audiences they had in mind (even Luke, who tells us in his prologue he is writing an orderly account, doesn’t specify what “orderly” means).

The exact sequence of events surrounding the healing of Peter's mother-in-law is not 100% certain. The Synoptic Gospels do not present their material in the same order, because the authors never intended them to do so.

Comment: Right.  Starting with "*In the beginning*" isn't the only reason John's gospel should be considered the first book in the Greek scriptures. It lays the basic chronological framework in which the other three gospels can be understood.  Anyone starting biblical study should start with John.  (It also allows Luke to flow naturally into Acts, its sequel.)

Answer (score 1):

The leper was healed first, after Jesus came down from the mountain where he gave the sermon on the mount(ch. 5-7, Matthew 8:1); Mark simply places the story at the end of his first chapter(1:40-45), giving no immediate context thereto.

As for the second question, Luke essentially backtracks in ch. 5 vss. 1-11 from Jesus' first visit to Capernaum(as recorded in the synoptics) to a time before he gave his sermon on the mount, which is not anything surprising in Luke(there are notable exceptions), also given that he doesn't mention the specifics of the sermon on the mount until ch. 6 vss. 20-49; so Matthew and Mark are correct in saying that Peter was 'called' before he entered Capernaum to heal his mother-in-law(which is fairly logical), though it were, according to John 1, not the first time he had met Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Luke's order is correct. It makes more sense that Peter, James & John would leave everything to follow Jesus if they had already:

heard him preach and teach (Luke 4:31, Luke 5:1-3)
seen him cast out demons (Luke 4:35, 41)
seen him heal illnesses and diseases (Luke 4:39-40)
seen him do a miracle in their realm (Luke 5:6-10)

Just my two cents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Expressions like "*I believe*" and "*my*" generally don't belong in properly constructed answers (or questions) on Stack Exchange sites.  Unlike comments, the postings should be objective and impersonal.

Answer (score 0):

There are no mistakes in God's Word.
There were clearly two calls.  Although
the first and second calls of these four disciples have similarities, close examination will show that these were two separate instances.

Notice six differences between this second time that Jesus called these disciples, here in Luke, and the first calling recorded in Matthew 4:18-22 and Mark 1:16-20.

1. In Luke, Andrew and Peter were on the shore washing their nets. In the first call, they were in their boats out on the lake casting a net into the sea.
2. James and John were also on the shore washing their nets, whereas in the first call, they were in the ship with their father mending their nets.
3. Only the second call shows Jesus using one of their boats from which to teach the people.
4. Only this second call records the miraculous catch of fish.
5. Peter’s reaction to the miraculous catch (Luke 5:8) is not recorded in the first call.
6. In Luke, James and John brought their ship to land and forsook all. In Matthew and Mark, they left the washing of their nets and forsook all.

These differences prove that Jesus called these four disciples to follow Him on two different occasions and vindicate Luke’s chronological listing of this event. By Andrew Wommack

Comment: I'm confused - this question is about Peter's Mother in Law. Are you saying Jesus healed her on two separate occasions?